# using \middle| to include limits during an integration process

Tags: symbols

i need to include limits (lower and upper ) in the ``\middle|` to solution to an integration.

```
\begin{eqnarray}
 Area &=& \int_{-1}^{2}(7-x^2)dx \\
&=& \left[\left(7x-\frac{1}{3}x^3\right) \middle| \right] \\ % here is where i wish it to occur
&=& \left[7.2-\frac{1}{3}(8)\right]- \left[7(-1)-\frac{1}{3}(-1)\right] \\
&=& 18 
\end{eqnarray}
```

Comment: To the `\middle`? I've never seen that syntax before. Here users write it as *limits* to the `]`, i.e. `]_1^2`. And BTW please don't use `eqnarray`.

Comment: I've seen `[...]` and limits attached to the right bracket or `...|` and limits attached to the bar; never brackets *and* bar.

Comment: i am still new at this, so apart from eqnarray what do you recommend?

Comment: `[...]_{lower}^{upper}`

Comment: instead of `eqnarray`, look at `split` or `align` from `amsmath`.  see [eqnarray vs align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/579).

Answer (score 1):

(Summary of comments.)

You can add the limits after the bracket using `[...]_{lower}^{upper}`. Having both brackets and bar is at best unusual, so stick to one or the other.

Also as mentioned, `eqnarray` should not be used, environments defined by `amsmath` is preferred (see [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align)). Which environment to use depends on what type of numbering you prefer. `align` gives you a number for each line, `aligned` (or `split`) inside an `equation` gives you a single number for the whole group of equations, and `align*` gives you no numbers at all.

I also used `\text{...}` for `Area`, and I added a thin space (`\,`) before `dx`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Each step numbered:
\begin{align}
 \text{Area} &= \int_{-1}^{2}(7-x^2)\,dx \\
&= \left[\left(7x-\frac{1}{3}x^3\right) \right]_{-1}^{2} \\ 
&= \left[7\cdot2-\frac{1}{3}(8)\right]- \left[7(-1)-\frac{1}{3}(-1)\right] \\
&= 18 
\end{align}

One number for all:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 \text{Area} &= \int_{-1}^{2}(7-x^2)\,dx \\
&= \left[\left(7x-\frac{1}{3}x^3\right) \right]_{-1}^{2} \\ 
&= \left[7\cdot2-\frac{1}{3}(8)\right]- \left[7(-1)-\frac{1}{3}(-1)\right] \\
&= 18 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

No numbers:
\begin{align*}
 \text{Area} &= \int_{-1}^{2}(7-x^2)\,dx \\
&= \left[\left(7x-\frac{1}{3}x^3\right) \right]_{-1}^{2} \\ 
&= \left[7\cdot2-\frac{1}{3}(8)\right]- \left[7(-1)-\frac{1}{3}(-1)\right] \\
&= 18 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```